# ballerina: tainted value passed to sensitive parameter

Tags: ballerina

I'm new to ballerina. I want to get a user parameter from the command line and set it to the json payload.
Something like this:

```
ballerina run client.bal testInput
```

Following is my client.bal

```
endpoint http:Client clientEndpoint {
    url: "http://localhost:9090"
};

function main(string... args) {
    http:Request req = new;
    string userInput = args[0];

    json jsonMsg = {input: userInput};
    req.setJsonPayload(jsonMsg);
```

But when I do that I get a compilation error: tainted value passed to sensitive parameter 'payload'

I tried to do a validation as follows but still does get the error.

```
string userInput = "empty";
if(!(args[0] == "")) {
    userInput = args[0];
}
```

Does anyone know a workaround for this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The untaint unary expression is a quick way to fix the compilation error here. But the correct approach is to properly do the validation of the content before it is passed into the secure function.

For example we could have a validate/sanitize function which takes the tainted value and return the untainted value after doing some validation as below.

```
function validate(string input) returns @untainted string {
    string regEx = "[^a-zA-Z]";
    return input.replace(regEx, "");
}
```

In the above example, by using the `@untainted` annotation, we can mark function return value as a untainted value. This value can now be directly passed into the secure function which expects a untainted value. So we can rewrite your example as below.

```
import ballerina/http;

endpoint http:Client clientEndpoint {
    url: "http://localhost:9090"
};

function main(string... args) {
    http:Request req = new;
    string userInput = validate(args[0]);
    json jsonMsg = {input: userInput};
    req.setJsonPayload(jsonMsg);
    // rest of the program
}

function validate(string input) returns @untainted string {
    string regEx = "[^a-zA-Z]";
    return input.replace(regEx, "");
}
```

The above validate function is just an example only. But based on the requirement, we can write the function to do the actual validation and return the secured content. More information is available at : https://ballerina.io/learn/by-example/taint-checking.html

Answer (score 2):

I searched about ballerina taint check. The path parameter in HTTP Client call is designated as security-sensitive. The compiler generates an error when untrusted data passed into a security-sensitive parameter

"untaint" unary expression can be used to denote that the proceeding value is trusted. But it is essential to do a proper data validation to make sure input does not result in a security threat.

Therefore we can fix the compilation error like this.

```
json jsonMsg = {input: untaint userInput};
```

But it is important to always validate the inputs. Cheers!!!